# Redirect any subdomain to main domain EXCEPT specific subdomains

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cpanel, server

Pretty much self explanatory .htaccess question but just to clarify...

for example :

redirect

```
*.example.com to --> example.com
```

EXCEPT

```
mobile.example.com (do NOT redirect)
forum.example.com (do NOT redirect)
```

etc...

or is it better to do the configuration directly inside cPanel ?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(mobile|forum)\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=302]
```

Comment: I tried but it's not working :'( and I also tried via cPanel to redirect *.example.com to example.com and still... not working bro... What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: You have to place this as very first rule in the `DocumentRoot/.htaccess` of **each and every domain** you want to redirect.

Comment: I think that I didn't explain myself very well bro, I need to redirect NON EXISTING subdomain to main domain.

Comment: Non existing subdomain won't even reach to your web server since DNS won't be resolved for them.

Comment: There was a time that I did it in the past via cPanel but I forgot how... I thing it was like *.mydomain.com -> mydomain.com but for some reason it's not working anymore